# How to find all lines with equal distance to two points in 2D space?

Tags: linear-algebra

In 2D space: I've been given two points `a`, `b` and need to find all lines, that have same distance to these two points.

From my laical perspective I think, that solution are all lines, that are either:

- parallel to line going through `a` and `b`: `{ x + < a-b > | x is vector}`
- going through middle between `a` and `b`: `{ (a+b)/2 + < x > | x is vector }`

And if `a = b`, then solution is all possible lines.

However, how do I prove that my solution is correct? And how can I notate them without repeating same lines, ie.: `(1,1) + <(1,1)> = (2,2) + <(1,1)>`

*Disclaimer: it's preparation for exam.*

Answer (score 1):

If the line is equidistant from both the points, then if we drop perpendiculars from both the points onto the line they will be equal in length. We make cases:

- If both perpendiculars are on the same side, then it is easy to see that the line is parallel to the line passing through the two points
- If the two perpendiculars are on opposite sides, then we can join the two points. Now using elementary geometry techniques we can prove that the line passes through their midpoint.

There can be no more cases, and the given cases have been fully worked out, thus these are the only possible lines.